# How to connect 24" Apple Display to HDMI output of Mac Mini 2011?

Tags: display, mac-mini, hdmi, displayport

Trying to have two monitors connected to Mac Mini mid-2011. It has one Mini DisplayPort and one HDMI outputs.

I have 27" monitor connected to Mini Display port of the Mac Mini mid-2011. I was going to connect 24" Apple display to it, but can't find anywhere on internet male-HDMI/female-Mini DisplayPort adapter.

There are the other way around (male DP to female HDMI) available, but not the one to connect 24" display as a second one.

I was thinking about finding a male HDMI–to something in between–to female Mini DisplayPort cables, but can't figure out what that "something in between" could be that would carry on digital signal.

Any advices?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, adapters like that don't exist, AFAIK.

That is, you can't just convert from HDMI to DisplayPort via a simple cable. The [Mini] DisplayPort to HDMI adapters aren't just cables, they contain IC's that provide an HDMI interface. I don't know of any such adapter that works in the other direction.